# I have several columns from different tables I need to combine into one so that they are separate rows in the result

Tags: sql, oracle

Data Example

***table1***

```
Value   component1
1            456
```

***table2***

```
Value   component2 
1            555A
```

***table3***

```
value   component3
 2          356
```

***Output I get***

```
Value     component1     component2    component3
1             456             555A
2                                          356
```

***Output I want - Separate rows***

```
Value         component
1               456
1               555A
2               356
```

Comment: Post the query you tried.

Comment: Is there anyway to use the union if the datatypes are not the same? Our dba created component 1 and 3 as number and 2 as Varchar2.

Answer (score 0):

You can use union like this:

```
SELECT * FROM TableA
UNION
SELECT * FROM TableB
UNION
SELECT * FROM TableC
UNION
SELECT * FROM TableD
```

refer to this page if you need more info:
[use union](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191141(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: I have mix matched datatypes.

Comment: well the column data types should be the same.Check the DataType for each of the query's fields   and make sure they agree with the DataType  of the other query's fields in the same position.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **UNION ALL** and make aliasing same as parameters on each tables. Please see below:

```
SELECT `value`,`component1` as 'component' FROM `table1`
UNION ALL
SELECT `value`,`component2` as 'component' FROM `table2`
UNION ALL
SELECT `value`,`component3` as 'component' FROM `table3`
```

You need set same expression/aliasing on each table you want to merge.
Please refer to this link if you want to know more
[MySQL Union and Union All Operators Primer](https://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/mysql-union-and-union-all-operators-primer.html)

Comment: I have mix matched datatypes.

Answer (score 0):

```
    with cte as 
    (
    Select value from table1
    union 
    Select value from table2
    union 
    Select value from table3
    )
    select cte.value
     , table1.Value as component1
    , table2.Value as component2
    , table3.Value as component3
from cte
left outer join table1 on table1.value = cte.value
left outer join table2 on table2.value = cte.value
left outer join table3 on table3.value = cte.value
```

Comment: I have mix matched datatypes.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: using your example value from table1 is number and value from table2 is a varchar2.

Comment: Cast all non-number columns to varchar. E.g. Cast(value as varchar(10))

Answer (score 0):

Regarding what you've said so far, TO_CHAR might help.

```
SQL> create table table1 (value number, component1 number);

Table created.

SQL> create table table2 (value number, component2 varchar2(20));

Table created.

SQL> create table table3 (value number, component3 number);

Table created.

SQL> insert all
  2    into table1 values (1, 456)
  3    into table2 values (1, '555A')
  4    into table3 values (2, 356)
  5  select * From dual;

3 rows created.

SQL>
SQL> select t1.value, to_char(t1.component1) component from table1 t1 union
  2  select t2.value, t2.component2                    from table2 t2 union
  3  select t3.value, to_char(t3.component3)           from table3 t3;

     VALUE COMPONENT
---------- ----------------------------------------
         1 456
         1 555A
         2 356

SQL>
```